# reCaptcha table style break - appears to have an extra border on the bottom, and white borders around buttons

Tags: php, css, recaptcha

reCaptcha is part of the wp-members plugin added to the site. For some reason, when it renders on the page though, i'm seeing white gaps between the buttons, and an extra border at the bottom. I can do html and css, but php is not my forte. Anybody know what's causing this or how I can fix it? Appears in opera, chrome, and firefox. also tested out the other themes for it (black, clean, etc) and all of them have similar problems.

[link to page](http://www.glowingwithhealth.com/members-area/)

[link to screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWUHL.png)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. In my case it was caused by a height setting I had assigned to all td elemets. I soved it by giving the respective table an ID like so:

```
    #table_id td
 {
    height: 60px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a html/CSS styling issue, and not caused by php. Check paddings, margins etc

Comment: Do you have any ideas as to what in the css may be causing this? I played with the styles in the page source, but couldn't figure it out. I think that it maybe an issue with the images that are being used as the background for the captcha table, because this is what is being used: http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/img/white/sprite.png   Is there any way to manually edit the code for the captcha, and if so, where can I find that code?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same, the cause is that the input has been set to: display: block.

This worked for me:

```
#recaptcha_widget_div input{display: inline;}
```